# TableView replacement for TableViewColumn in Qt Quick 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qtquickcontrols

In Qt Quick Controls 1 we can style different columns from a model with `TableViewColumn`:

```
TableView {

    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {title: "1"; role: "one"; width: 70 }
    TableViewColumn {title: "2"; role: "two"; width: 70   }
    TableViewColumn {title: "3"; role: "three"; width: 70 }

    model: theModel

}
```

How can we achieve a similar result in Qt Quick 2 if there is no more `TableViewColumn` for the `TableView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Qt 5.12 you can use [`TableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) QML type.
But to have everything you want you need to include `Qt.labs.qmlmodels`. It all is available in Qt 5.15 (use [online installer](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/online_installers/)).

Actual implementation will hardly depend on your requirements, but here is an example of how it could be done.

- Let's say you are going to use [`TableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) to show some data you have in JSON format. In this case [`TableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html) will be a perfect fit, since it is designed to work with JavaScript/JSON data, where each row is a simple key-pair object without requiring the creation of a custom [`QAbstractTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) subclass in C++.
- You need to declare what columns do you need to have in your model by using [`TableModelColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodelcolumn.html), e.g.: `TableModelColumn { display: "checked" }`.
- For loading real data into model use its [`rows`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html#rows-prop) property; data should be in the form of an array of rows, e.g.:

```
rows: [
        // Each property is one cell/column.
        {
          checked: false,
          amount: 1,
          type: "Apple",
          price: 1.50
        },
        {
          checked: true,
          amount: 4,
          type: "Orange",
          price: 2.50
        },
        ...
      ]
```

- Most interesting part here is appliance of delegate -- here it be [`DelegateChooser`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html), since it allows a view to use different delegates for different types of items in the model. So here you can do almost everything to tweak your cells. E.g.: you can use [`ProgressBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-progressbar.html) component as your delegate for a cell:

```
DelegateChoice {
  column: 1
  delegate: ProgressBar {
    enabled: false
    width: 100
    from: 0.0
    to: 10.0
    value: model.display
  }
}
```

As result you could easily get this application entirely in QML (whiteout need to use C++ and/or old QtQuick.Controls):

[image: Example of application]

Please refer to [this repository](https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/TestTableViewModels) to get full application.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I found out `DelegateChooser` is exactly what I was looking for.