TableViewColumn in Quick.Controls 2.15
I need to rewrite the view from QTableView to qml when using quick.controls 2.15 in qt 5.15 in quick 2.15. I have a c++ model, but I need to display them in a table, with the ability to display them the same way as in a regular QTableView table with sorting by clicking on the column name. I know the number of columns in advance. in Quick.Controls 1.4, this task is perfectly solved using TableViewColumn. Using it, everything works fine. But I need to write my application specifically on the version of quick.controls 2.15. How can I do this?
I have very little experience in QML, My model is made from Qabstractitemmodel, or you can use QAbstractTableModel (This is not very important). I was thinking of just displaying the data in the Tableview via the TableViewColumn, but alas it is not available in Controls 2.15

It's been moved to QtQuick. See the documentation and the "Import Statement".

@musicamante, I didn't find it. Can you show me an example? For example: Controls 1.4: code TableViewColumn {                 role: "age"                 title: "Age"                 width: tableView.widthColumn                 resizable: true                 delegate: Item {                     TextField {                         width: parent.width                         text: model.age                         onEditingFinished: {  customModel.updateRow(styleData.row, text, 1); }} } } 

What didn't you find? It's just on top of that page.

@musicamante I've seen that this can be found in quick 2.15. But I'm using quick 2.15 and controls 2.15 at the same time. My question is how to properly translate my TableViewColumn from Controls 1.4 to Controls 2.15.

Just add the TableViewColumn to TableView as explained in its documentation.

@musicamante I already have everything working in Controls 1.4. But I need to upgrade to the Controls 2.15 version and there is no TableViewColumn anymore. And I need to implement a replacement for this TableViewColumn so that it does not differ in any way from version 1.4

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64403258
